# AWS SQS Batch SendMessageBatchRequest is very Slow

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

My application posts 10 messages per request to AWS-SQS using SendMessageBatchRequest. The size of each message is less than 250 bytes. The application is expected to post about a million records per day. But the rate at which the messages are getting posted is extremely slow to accomplish this.

```
AmazonSQS sqs = null;
sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "SecretKey"));
//the below entries are added via a for loop picking the messages from a queue
//the typical queue size will be 20k messages
//AmazonSQSClient is created once and is used until the code comes out of the for loop

List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry>();
entries.add(new SendMessageBatchRequestEntry(messageBatchRequestId, "250kbJSONString"));
 //Once the batch count reaches 10,the following code is called 

CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest("CLIENT-TEST");
String myQueueUrl = sqs.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();

SendMessageBatchRequest sendMessageBatchRequest = new    SendMessageBatchRequest(myQueueUrl);

sendMessageBatchRequest.setEntries(entries);
long timeBeforePost = System.currentTimeMillis();
SendMessageBatchResult smbResult = sqs.sendMessageBatch(sendMessageBatchRequest);
long afterPost = System.currentTimeMillis();
log.trace("time taken %s ",(afterPost-timeBeforePost));
```

The Time taken in ms for each post is captured and here is the typical output

```
time taken 57
time taken 37
time taken 31
time taken 322
time taken 48
time taken 153
time taken 278
time taken 86
time taken 35
time taken 28
time taken 30
time taken 57
time taken 43
time taken 314
time taken 5587
time taken 42
time taken 4789
time taken 4831
time taken 66
time taken 6239
time taken 50
time taken 38
time taken 4833
time taken 40
time taken 4896
time taken 27
time taken 16634
```

Is this normal to have some posts taking 7,16 etc seconds to return, I have some posts with 300 seconds as well to return from the method call.Am I missing something here , My Application is currently single threaded and I am planning to make it multi-threaded to process the messages in parallel but again some messages taking seconds and some taking tens/hundreds of seconds is something seriously wrong. Please help .

Thanks a Ton

Comment: Where is the posting being done from? An EC2 instance or something local to you? If EC2, how big is your instance(s)?

Comment: Its not EC2 . A local machine : model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5320  @ 1.86GHz    16G of Memroy . The app is running on apache-Tomcat instance with 2G of memory

Answer (score 3):

My first guess then would be a latency issue between your local machine and SQS, SQS can certainly process incoming messages a lot faster than the numbers you are seeing.

Perhaps the best bet is to spin up an EC2 instance for a few hours, similar in size to your local machine, and same test to see if the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating one AmazonSQS client and reusing it for each request. The client provides connection pooling and keeps the connections open to optimize reuse. It may also be looking up the region to find an endpoint to connect to. It is best to reuse aws clients throughout the entire application rather than for each request.

> Service clients in the SDK are thread-safe and, for best performance, you should treat them as long-lived objects. Each client has its own connection pool resource that is shut down when the client is garbage collected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/creating-clients.html